# How to merge my local repository with remote repository on Bitbucket?

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I am developing open-stack project which is available on github. Now My team-mates downloaded on their local system and make remote repository on bit-bucket, I want to synchronize with bit-bucket repository on remote. So that I get updated repository on my local system, How I will do that. 
I already done

```
[vagrant@localhost horizon]$ git remote rm origin
[vagrant@localhost horizon]$ git remote add origin ssh://git@bitbucket.org/user_name/repo_name.git
[vagrant@localhost horizon]$ git push -u origin master
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '131.103.20.167' to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Comment: Have you added the ssh key to your account?

Comment: @pratZ I am getting error like that  Please make sure you have the correct access rights

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add the new bitbucket repository as remote.

```
git remote add neworigin <bitbucket-repo-url>
```

You can then fetch and merge,

```
git fetch neworigin
git merge neworigin/<branch>
```

If you want to name it `origin` you will have to rename or delete the existing remote.

You also need to make sure you have added an SSH key to your account. [Read here on how to add an ssh key](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Add+an+SSH+key+to+an+account)
In case you do not have a public key. You can generate it by (inside the .ssh directory present in your home directory),

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "hello@world.com"
```

**UPDATE**

You are using `ssh` protocol, use the `https` url. It will then ask you for the username and password.

Comment: Thanks I checked linked you have shared. But I need just user name and password to login on remote repository on bit-bucket, How I will do this..

Comment: use https url instead.

Comment: login to your bitbucket account. Choose your repository. On top right corner the url will be displayed. There's a dropdown which should be currently showing you the `ssh` url. Click it and select `https`. Copy the new `https` url and use it as your remote url

Answer (score 0):

You can use the tool TortoiseHG or SourceTree to sync the remote repository with local

Refer this [link](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Sourcetree+Git+GUI+on+Windows) to clone it at local